# lr.predict_proba() возвращает ошибку: "ValueError: X has 6 features per sample; expecting 32"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, машинное-обучение

В исходном датафрейме 32 поля.
На выходе надо 6.

```
df_test=df_test[['CR_PROD_CNT_IL','REST_AVG_CUR','AGE','REST_AVG_PAYM','CLNT_SETUP_TENOR','ID']]`
```

При обучении на строке `pb1 = lr.predict_proba(df_test)[:,1]`

```
ValueError: X has 6 features per sample; expecting 32
```

Как перезаписать датафрейм что бы не выдавал ошибку ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем суть вопроса? Попробуйте привести в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Также рекомендую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-pandas-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn)

Comment: вопрос решился вашим прошлым комментарием про обучением машины. передать ей необходимые столбцы.

Comment: Укажите код в текстовом виде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если модель обучалась на 32 признаках (features), то и при тестировании/предсказании она будет ожидать на входе 32 признака (столбца) о чем и сообщает текст ошибки.

Т.е. и при обучении модели и при тестировании/предсказании число признаков (столбцов) должно совпадать.

---

Чтобы прочитать только избранные столбцы из CSV файла используйте параметр [`usecols=list_of_column_names`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
cols = ['CR_PROD_CNT_IL','REST_AVG_CUR','AGE','REST_AVG_PAYM','CLNT_SETUP_TENOR','ID']

df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=cols)
```

Comment: Благодарю. Тогда, есть способ считать с csv файла заранее известный список атрибутов тех же 6 а не все 32 ??